# how can i control the coordinates (position) of the printed barcode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Am trying to print barcode labels, but when the label come out the printer the barcode printed in the top(need in the bottom), how can i control the coordinates of the barcode?

```
my code is

Private Sub printdc128_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim bc128 As New BarcodeLib.Barcode.Linear()
    bc128.Data = TextBox2.Text
    bc128.BarHeight = 60.0
    bc128.BarWidth = 3.0
    bc128.Resolution = 124
    bc128.drawBarcode(e.Graphics)
End Sub
```

Comment: Who is the vendor of your barcode control, there should be a Location property of some sort.

Comment: yes there is align left, right, top and bottom.
but can i use this: e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, New Drawing.PointF(10, 90)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub printdc128_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim bc128 As New BarcodeLib.Barcode.Linear()
    ' Insert text
    e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox1.Text, New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16.0F), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, New System.Drawing.PointF(10.0F, 10.0F))

    ' Select Code Type
    bc128.Type = BarcodeLib.Barcode.BarcodeType.CODE128
    ' Select data source
    bc128.Data = TextBox2.Text
    ' Choose Unit of Measures
    bc128.UOM = BarcodeLib.Barcode.UnitOfMeasure.PIXEL
    ' Barcode Height and Width
    bc128.BarHeight = 40.0
    bc128.BarWidth = 2.0
    ' Convert text to stream
    Dim bc128stream As New MemoryStream()

    bc128.drawBarcode(bc128stream)
    ' Convert Stream to image
    img = Drawing.Image.FromStream(bc128stream)
    ' Draw the image and Choose the coordinates(X,Y)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, New Drawing.PointF(10, 90))

End Sub
```